# How can I compile files when my current working directory is not the default package?

Tags: java, linux

I have two files in Linux, both in the default package, `AddSingleInstance.java` and `Finder.java`

I am creating an instance of `AddSingleInstance` in `Finder`:

```
AddSingleInstance ai = new AddSingleInstance();
```

When I compile Finder.java file it gives the below error:

```
Finder.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
AddSingleInstance ai = new AddSingleInstance();
    ^
```

I'm compiling from a different directory.  How can I get both files to compile successfully?

Comment: are they in the same package?

Comment: @BevynQ They are in same directory.. I am not using packages..  In windows it took classes directly from the folder ( May be it was netbeans ability)

Comment: @PaulHicks  I am using "javac" command for all java files.

Comment: That led me to the solution.  See answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, your java files should be on your classpath so that javac knows where to find them.  You can either manually set the classpath:

```
javac -classpath javadir javadir\Finder.java
java -cp javadir Finder
```

Or use the default classpath of `.:$PATH`.  The easiest way to do that is

```
cd javadir
javac Finder.java
java Finder
```

I guess most people don't encounter this issue (I never have before!) because they run `javac` from their default package (the root of their source tree).

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same package then AddSingleInstance should be accessible in Finder and vice versa.

However if they are in separate packages, then add the following line at the top of Finder.java (after package declaration)

```
import packageName.AddSingleInstance;
```

Comment: HI .. tnx for replying. I am not using packages. I just  have different classes and in windows I have compiled in order so i had class files ready for the next java file. But it doesn't work the same in linux.  It says cannot find symbol.  DO we have method to import multiple classes to a java file so that i can create objects for them ( instead of creating packages). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible your source file is using Windows style line feeds.
Try using the program dos2unix to fix the line feeds and try recompiling. I'd also have to see the complete source file to help further, I'm assuming you have the imports at the top of the file.

Comment: Java ignores whitespace.  This can't be the problem, unless there's a bug in the compiler being used.